# How to close a UserControl after success button click in jquery asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Hi iam using jquery in asp.net

Ihave a user control with few contols and a SAVE button.

Iam writing Ajax calls to save data .

Iam getting my data saved Successfully. But after mu SUccess alert also my User Control Popup is still in the page. i just wanted to hide/close.

For that i tried this code and was not working.

```
        success: function (html) {
                     try {
                         alert("added successfuly");
                         $(".modalBackground").hide();
                     } catch (ex) {
                         alert("ErrCode:1");

                     }
```

MY ASCX:

WHich contains a ModalPopup with few fileds

```
     <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupContext" runat="server" 
           TargetControlID="btnContextPopup" BehaviorID="ModalPopupExtender" PopupControlID="pnlpopupContext" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
     </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

                 <panel ....>

                 TextBox1 
                 Textbox2
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server"       ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgbtnUpdateADDContext" TabIndex="8" ImageUrl="~/image_repository/UpdateVoyage.png" />
        </panel>
```

This is the Button which i use to save data., after this click if its success my UserControl Must be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function (html) {
         try {
              alert("Port added successfuly");
              $("PanelClassName").hide(); // Panel which is in ajax:ModalPopupExtender               
              } catch (ex) {
              alert("ErrCode:1");
              }
           return false;
       }
```

Comment: Yes, Check in page view source and put in there with prefix "#".

Comment: Yes i tried with PopupID its not working, i tried with css class its not wokring, i tried with behaviourid its not working

Comment: please replace "ModalPopupContext" id rendered in view source. with # prefix.

Comment: Yes sir i have used # before id and . before class still not working

Comment: what is the control ID in view source?

Comment: that is ModalPopup and i have given as $("#ModalPopup").hide();

Comment: no right click on page select page view source and find controlid. Then paste here.

Comment: Thanks for tring to help me.., i have found this id ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupContextMenu_pnlpopupContextInfo for ModalPop when i checked in browser

Comment: hey ya  $(".pnlpopupContextInfo").hide(); this is working, i have given a class to panel and used that class id...,

Comment: Id is not correctly working but when i took css class it is working fine.

Comment: $(".PanelClassName").hide(); You just update like this for new users ref it will be easy...

Answer (score 1):

simply put your UserControl Code in panel and than on success hide that panel

```
<asp:panel runnat="server" id="pnl">
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupContext" runat="server" 
           TargetControlID="btnContextPopup" BehaviorID="ModalPopupExtender" PopupControlID="pnlpopupContext" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
     </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

                 <panel ....>

                 TextBox1 
                 Textbox2
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server"       ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgbtnUpdateADDContext" TabIndex="8" ImageUrl="~/image_repository/UpdateVoyage.png" />
        </panel>
</panel>
```

**Now In success part**

```
 success: function (html) {
                     try {
                         alert("Port added successfuly");
                 var pnel= document.getElementById('<%= pnl.ClientID%>');
                     pnel.hide();
                     } catch (ex) {
                         alert("ErrCode:1");

                     }
```

Comment: generateRptbtn here means the ID of ModalPopup??

Comment: sorry i forget to chage id,its id of asp:panel,now see my answer

Comment: When i give panel id which is in user control is giving error as name doesnot exist in corrent context.., i tried with modalpopupId also, tried with css class name also still its not hiding

Comment: Given Panel class name its working fine, I have used ModalPopupextender with a panel and given panel class name. like $(".PanelClassName").hide(); Just remeber as Ref and Thanks for your help